# Does 50-622 Schwalbe Marathon plus winter fit my bike?

Tags: tire

So my bike original tires are 47-622 and I'm wondering does 50-622 Schwalbe Marathon plus winter fit my bike?

My bike: https://whitebikes.com/ax-290-ff-20/b/2461/

Comment: My rims are WHITE TD18 32h but not quite sure what those numbers are and what is the rim width

Comment: 622 is the diameter of the rim in millimeters. None of the numbers you mentioned are related to size, but I bet you can find 622 printed somewhere on the rim too.

Comment: This is probably a better question to ask white bikes support department rather than bicycles.se. Most likely the only thing preventing you fitting the larger tyre is the clearances in your frame which none of us can see/measure

Comment: Just a little tip: if you don't have calipers to measure your frame's clearance, you can try using a ruler to see how much of a gap there is. Look for the gaps between the tire and the front fork blades, the upper part of the fork (technically the fork crown, I think), and at the back between the chain or seat stays. You might expect the new tire to be about 1.5mm larger on each side, and probably 3mm taller. That's not much of a change, and I suspect the frame can fit it.